Can't remove my hyperglide cassette
How can I remove my cassette? I've been planning to replace them for a while now but can't really remove them, no matter what I do.
Im using a SHIMANO FH-TY500 hub, paired with a SHIMANO TOURNEY 7-Speed MTB Cassette Sprocket.


You have a freewheel, not a cassette, you need to remove it using a freewheel tool by unscrewing it. Unlike with a cassette, you do not need a chain whip.

But it looks like the SHIMANO FH-TY500 hub has a freehub? It’s strange because the thing in OP’s photo doesn’t look like the freehub cassette lockrings I’m used to but it certainly looks like it has the internal “teeth” for a cassette lockring tool.

Indeed, it really does not look like lockrings I am used to, but I stand corrected.

Image definitely looks like a freewheel to me - this answer seems correct.   But googling OP's model number returns https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano/FH-TY500-7-NT(130).html  which is a freehub.  I suspect they've misread the model number, or its a really old part with a similar model number.

@Criggie Thank you for the heads up. I will undelete this answer because it really looks like a freewheel.

100% a freewheel in the picture. I suspect they're looking at published specs on a bike that's had its wheel replaced.

The SHIMANO FH-TY500 hub is a freehub design (not the older freewheel where the ratcheting mechanism is built into the cassette).
You’ll need:

a cassette lockring tool (e.g. Shimano TL-LR10) and a spanner or ratchet to turn it.



a chain whip (you might get away with a bench vise and an old chain)


You’ll need quite some force/torque to remove the lockring. Put the chain whip on the second largest sprocket and apply as much force on the spanner/ratchet as you can. The lockring has a normal right-handed thread (i.e. loosens when turned counter-clockwise).
